# Razor JavaScript Interop won't "window.close()" because of security issue

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a razor page which has a button for closing the browser window using `window.close()`, and it works fine in the initial browser window when the app starts, because according to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close), you can close a window this way if 1) it's the first page in the browser history or 2) it's closing the window with the same script that opened it.

My page isn't opened by a script, but by starting the app, then navigating to another page. Once I hit the 2nd page, `window.close()` will trigger the `Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them` error.

How do force my browser window to close once I'm on a different page?

Comment: Perhaps consider rendering the popup's contents in an iframe, and have the parent listen for a message from the iframe to close the window when its ready...

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very clear that browsers restrict the ability to close windows or tabs that were not opened by JavaScript for security reasons.

Be sure your `<a>` does not contain any link:

```
<a id="navigateButton">Navigate to New Page</a>
<script>
   
    document.getElementById('navigateButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
        window.open("/Home/Privacy", "_blank");
        window.close();
    });
</script>
```